# Given a file directory, any short cut to open the file in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

If you're given a full path to a file, say "blah/yadayada/file1.java", does IntelliJ offer any keyboard shortcut to open that file directly in the IDE?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html

Answer (score 0):

IFAIK The closest you get cut and pasting the full path in IntelliJ and searching for a type (class/interface/enum) replacing / by . or searching for a resource file.